# Google Drive API - managing propagation delay on remove permissions cascade

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I'm using Make (formerly Integromat) to remove permissions on Folders, files and subfolders using Google Drive APIs.

When removing permissions on a folder (either through the UI or the API), Google will recursively remove like permissions from any files in that folder and any subfolders. There is naturally a propagation delay whilst this process completes.

So far so good.

Drive will necessarily leave some file and subfolder permissions intact where those permissions were specifically granted on that/those objects. We therefore need to iterate through those files and subfolders, checking for any residual permissions and removing them with the Remove Permissions API.

The problem here is that there is no way to determine whether permission removals are still being processed (propagated) from the parent folder. THe only (crude) way I can think of dealing with this is to introduce a fixed delay time between permission removals. If the delay time isn't long enough, Remove Permissions returns an error when trying to remove a permission which has already been removed.

Has anyone dealt with this in a more effective way?

Comment: Where's the folder located? If it was on a shared drive, you could use `permissionDetails[].inherited` and `permissionDetails[].inheritedFrom` to identify the permissions that were directly given to the item, and not inherited. Otherwise, I don't think there's a way to identify these, in which case the delay might be your best option. Is it a problem that `Remove Permissions returns an error`?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me.
Yes, Remove Permissions returns an error (something like Permission ID not found).
I've done some more testing and can confirm categorically that the issue is propagation delay on removing inherited permissions.
I'll take a look at permissionDetails[] though if I need to provide a permission ID then I suspect Im going to run into the same problem

Comment: I don't think you need to provide `permissionId`, you can call [Permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) and iterate. But, again, I don't think these fields are populated if you are not on a shared drive. Also, if you are getting `Remove Permissions returns an error` when removing permissions via code, I think you could tackle this via `try...catch`.